# Can't delete files in KMPlayer

Tags: windows-10, kmplayer

After installing the latest version of KMPlayer on my Windows 10 Pro computer, I no longer have the option to delete movies I'm watching. The old `Ctrl+Shift+Del` doesn't work anymore. Nothing happens when I press them and I can't find an option to bind any keys to delete movies.

Has this option been removed in KMPlayer? In that case, what other movie players have that option?

Comment: Try Shift + Del while playing the file.

Comment: I have tride any combination of Ctrl, Shift and Delete and nothing works. Also, there is no option in the shortcuts to assaing any keys to delete files. It's simply not there.

Comment: Why don't you file a bug report on their site?